# pandas dataframe drop column name None

Tags: python, pandas

As title. I have a dataframe with `None` column and I want to drop them.

```
sheet_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 181 entries, 1 to 181
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------           --------------  -----  
 0   Timestamp        181 non-null    object 
 1   Score            181 non-null    object 
 2   Full Name        181 non-null    object 
 3   None             181 non-null    object
```

The column name is not string `"None"`, it is `None` object.

I attempted to `drop` as per usual :

```
sheet_df.drop(sheet_df[None], axis=1, inplace=True)
sheet_df.drop(None, axis=1, inplace=True)
sheet_df.drop(np.nan, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

All the above, do not work.

Reason of dropping instead of taking specific column is because the columns are inconsistent so `drop` the column is a better option.

However, if there is a better way of doing it or I missed something, please guide. Thank you.

Comment: When you say,  they "do not work" - what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `None` coincides with the default values of the arguments to `DataFrame.drop`, confusion arises and no drop happens.

A remedy is to supply a list with 1 element:

```
df = df.drop([None], axis=1)
```

or equivalently,

```
df = df.drop(columns=[None])
```

Comment: This is good. Better syntax than `del df[None]`

Comment: I get `KeyError: '[None] not found in axis'` for both solution

Comment: @user6308605 Can you share the output of `df.columns.tolist()` here?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `del`

```py
...
del sheet_df[None]
```

Comment: Updated it after test. `del` does the job